# How to evaluate this surface integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification, surface-integrals

The ends of a circular cylinder of radius $a$ and axis $OZ$ are in the planes $z = 0$, $z = 2a$. If $S$ denotes the complete surface of the cylinder (including the plane ends), then how to evaluate the surface integral
$$
\int\int_S z \, dx \, dy? 
$$

My Attempt:

> On the surface $S_1$ of the cylinder, we have
> $$
> \mathbf{r} = \big( a \cos \phi, a \sin \phi, z \big),
> $$
> where
> $$
> 0 \leq \phi \leq 2 \pi, \ 0 \leq z \leq 2a. 
> $$
> Then we have
> $$
> \begin{align} 
> \mathbf{r}_\phi &= \big( -a \sin \phi, \, a \cos \phi, \, 0 \big), \\ 
> \mathbf{r}_z &= \big( 0, \, 0, \, 1 \big),
> \end{align}
> $$
> and so
> $$
> \mathbf{r}_\phi \times \mathbf{r}_z = \big( a \cos \phi, \, a \sin \phi, \, 0 \big). 
> $$
> Therefore the element $dS_1$ of the surface area is given by
> $$
> dS_1 = \left| \mathbf{r}_\phi \times \mathbf{r}_z \right| = a,
> $$
> and so
> \begin{align}
> \int\int_{S_1} z \, dS_1 &= \int_{z=0}^{z=2a} \int_{\phi = 0}^{\phi=2\pi} az \, d\phi \, dz \\
> &= \int_{z=0}^{z=2a} 2\pi a z \, dz \\
> &= \pi a \left[z^2 \right]_{z=0}^{z=2a} \\
> &= 4 \pi a^3.
> \end{align}

> On the surface $S_2$ of the end $z = 0$, we have
> $$
> \mathbf{r} = \big( r \cos \phi, \, r \sin \phi, 0 \big),
> $$
> where
> $$
> 0 \leq r \leq a, \ 0 \leq \phi \leq 2 \pi.
> $$
> So we have
> \begin{align}
> \mathbf{r}_r &= \big( \cos \phi, \, \sin \phi, \, 0 \big), \\
> \mathbf{r}_{\phi} &= \big( -r \sin \phi, \, r \cos \phi, \, 0 \big),
> \end{align}
> and thus
> $$
> \mathbf{r}_r \times \mathbf{r}_{\phi} = \big( 0, \, 0, \, r \big). 
> $$
> Thus the element $dS_2$ of the surface area is given by
> $$
> dS_2 = \left| \mathbf{r}_r \times \mathbf{r}_{\phi} \right| = r,
> $$
> and
> \begin{align}
> \int \int_{S_2} z \, dS_2 &= \int_{r=0}^{r=a} \int_{\phi=0}^{\phi = 2\pi} 0 r  \, d\phi \, dz \\
> &= 0.
> \end{align}

> Finally, on the surface $S_3$ of the end $z = 2a$, we have
> $$
> \mathbf{r} = \big( r \cos \phi, \, r \sin \phi, 2a \big),
> $$
> where
> $$
> 0 \leq r \leq a, \ 0 \leq \phi \leq 2 \pi.
> $$
> So we have
> \begin{align}
> \mathbf{r}_r &= \big( \cos \phi, \, \sin \phi, \, 0 \big), \\
> \mathbf{r}_{\phi} &= \big( -r \sin \phi, \, r \cos \phi, \, 0 \big),
> \end{align}
> and thus
> $$
> \mathbf{r}_r \times \mathbf{r}_{\phi} = \big( 0, \, 0, \, r \big). 
> $$
> Thus the element $dS_3$ of the surface area is given by
> $$
> dS_3 = \left| \mathbf{r}_r \times \mathbf{r}_{\phi} \right| = r,
> $$
> and
> \begin{align}
> \int \int_{S_3} z \, dS_3 &= \int_{r=0}^{r=a} \int_{\phi=0}^{\phi = 2\pi} 2ar \, d\phi \, dz \\
> &= \int_{r=0}^{r=a} 4\pi a r \, dr \\
> &= 2 \pi a \left[ r^2 \right]_{r=0}^{r=a} \\
> &= 2 \pi a^3. 
> \end{align}

> Hence the total surface integral is given by
> $$
> \int\int_S z \, dS = \int\int_{S_1} z \, dS_1 + \int\int_{S_2} z \, dS_2 + \int\int_{S_3} z \, dS_3 = 4\pi a^3 + 0 + 2\pi a^3 = 6\pi a^3. 
> $$

Is this solution correct and clear enough in each and every detail? Or, are there any problems?

Comment: Just a suggestion (not necessary to follow) I'd advice you to use > with question and write just normally without >

Answer (score 1):

It's quite clear and systematic to me. Interestingly we can evaluate as the following for this particular case; define $z'=z-a$
$$
\int\int_{S}z\phantom{x}dx\phantom{.}dy\phantom{x}=\phantom{x}\int\int_{S}z'\phantom{x}dx\phantom{.}dy\phantom{x}+a\int\int_{S}\phantom{x}dx\phantom{.}dy
$$

The first term on the right evaluates to zero because of symmetry. The second term is simply product between $a$ and the cylinder's surface area.